# How to add a file from the active document directory

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document that creates a template page from a VBA script every time I need to insert a specific item into my document, its a great time saver, this includes an image. I have got a working foundation whereby it inserts the image and text wraps it where I want it to be, however the file path is an absolute one. I would like the file path to specify that the image file is within the same directory as the active document so that if I move the directory to a different location this macro will not be broken.

The problem is a little beyond my vba skills, I have worked out I should probably use the ActiveDocument.Path command but I am not sure how to. I appreciate your help. Thank you

Below is my code so far:

```
Sub Inser_Wrapped_Image()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture( _
        FileName:="C:\Users\Edoardo\Documents\My Work\PhD\SkyDrive\Tutoring\Houria\Image Replacement.jpg", _
        SaveWithDocument:=True, _
        Anchor:=Selection.Range)
    With shp
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdSquare
        .Left = 246
        .Top = 50
        .Width = 250
        .Height = 188
    End With
End Sub
```

I have tried writing it as follows but word freezes for a few seconds and then does nothing:

```
Sub Insert_image()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture( _
        FileName:=ActiveDocument.Path & "\Image.jpg", _
        SaveWithDocument:=True, _
        Anchor:=Selection.Range)
End Sub
```

Comment: That should work. It works on my system. Well you can try the solution I posted and let's hope it works.

Comment: **Edit** Hello again, I opened a new document saved it to the same directory and saved that macro (in the document directory in vba - its a .docm) and it still decides to freeze with any of the ThisDocument.Path or ActiveDocument.Path commands resulting in the image not being inserted. Dodgy word install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Inser_Wrapped_Image()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim imgpath As String

    imgpath = ThisDocument.Path
    imgpath = imgpath & "\" & "Image Replacement.jpg"

    Set shp = ThisDocument.Shapes.AddPicture( _
        FileName:=imgpath, SaveWithDocument:=True, _
        Anchor:=Selection.Range)
    With shp
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
        .Left = 246
        .Top = 50
        .Width = 250
        .Height = 188
    End With
End Sub
```

I used `ThisDocument` to explicitly load the picture to the document that contains the macro.
It will work both ways thought if you want to stick to `ActiveDocument`.

Comment: thank you for your help, for some reason using this type of pathing causes my word to freeze and not insert the image. Hence the later part of placing the image fails and causes VBA to return the error window. Could you happen to know why this could be?

Comment: And the line highlighted when you debug is `Activeworkbook.Path`? What version of word?

Comment: Hello again, no unfortunately for some reason neither the ActiveDocument.Path nor ThisDocument.Path seem to work because as it runs through the macro word seems to freeze at that point and then unfreezing, when it does so no image is entered into the document thereby entering debug on the 'With shp' etc line. I am on word 2013